# How to assign standard deviation using facet_grid operator?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used the ggplot using the folowing script

```
data <- fread("Book1.txt")
names(data)
days <- c("UD","D4","D6","D10","D16")
sample <-c("H1","H2","H3")
SD <- c('SD_UD', 'SD_D4', 'SD_D6', 'SD_D10','SD_16')
vol <- data.table(gather(data, days, expression, UD:D16))
volL <- data.table(gather(vol, expression, SD, SD_UD:SD_D16))
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
gg <-ggplot(volL, aes(days, expression, fill= sample)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.9, position = dodge) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=expression-SD, ymax=expression+SD), color= "grey", width=.1) +
 facet_grid(sample~.) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=days, labels = days) +
  ggtitle("Expression vs days")
```

Data table :

```
sample  UD  D4  D6  D10 D16 SD_UD   SD_D4   SD_D6   SD_D10  SD_D16
H1  9.96113E-05 0.000276321 0.105211427 0.098271655 0.06978369  1.17174E-05 9.84763E-05 0.03589122  0.05107505  0.017763717
H2  7.9913E-06  4.43916E-05 0.040212602 0.106493626 0.162614138 9.31988E-07 4.28076E-05 0.012332228 0.0441571   0.063304324
H3  0.000233391 0.000382084 0.001415172 0.003544547 0.018624673 0.000103126 0.000110262 0.000612986 0.000572592 0.010861883
```

Using the above script I got the following graph;
[image]

Problem: It did not assign the standard deviation according to the data.fram. Could anyone help me out how to assign the SD values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did assign the standard deviation according to the `data.frame`.. problem is the `data.frame` contains 4 different value of `SD` for each `expression`.
To solve, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

expression <- df %>% 
    select(sample,  UD:D16) %>% 
    gather(days, expr, UD:D16)

SD <- df %>% 
    select(sample, SD_UD:SD_D16) %>% 
    gather(days, SD, SD_UD:SD_D16) %>% 
    mutate(sample, days = gsub(x = days, pattern = 'SD_', ''), SD)

df1 <- inner_join(expression,SD)

gg <-ggplot(df1, aes(days, expr, fill = sample)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.9, position = dodge) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=expr-SD, ymax=expr+SD), color= "grey", width=.1) +
    facet_grid(sample~.) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=days, labels = days) +
    ggtitle("Expression vs days")
```

Hope this helps.